# How to increase or decrease numbers in a visual block on the fly?

Tags: regex, vim, numbers

I often find myself adding numbers on the fly to a list of numbers.

p.e.

```
    38
    12 x
   215 x
    98 x
    03 x
    23
```

What I want to do is to select a visual block of numbers (x in the above example)
and increase or decrease the numbers with another number.

I tried to do it using two macro's (I suppose one macro isn't possible):
@a to increase the number --> 5@a --> to increase every number with 5 (@a = '^Aj')
@x to decrease the number --> 5@x --> to decrease every number with 5 (@x = '^Xj')
but...

I don't know
1) how to use the macro only in my selection (without counting lines)
2) how to change the increase/decrease number on the fly without creating a whole new macro.
3) How to resolve this: when I add 100 to the above numbers, the numbers `12`, `98` and `03` are moved 1 character to the right.

Another solution is to create a function but it is i.m.o. to complex to add every time a value in an input box for a few numbers I have to change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have all your lines selected, you can do:

```
:'<,'>norm 5<C-v><C-a> <-- inserts ^A
```

to add `5` to every number.

The alignment problem can't be avoided AFAIK and yes, vimscript is probably the right tool for the job.

Comment: +1 good answer! the alignment auto-adjustment is possible, but need to write a small function or turn to some plugins..

Comment: @romainl, Tnx, You're right. I'm trying to create a script now. Is it possible to put a sign in a search to find out where the search comes from? p.e. let @/ = 'mysearch.recognizesign'?

Comment: No. `@/` would become something that is not in your buffer. What do you try to achieve with that?

Answer (score 1):

Increment the numbers isn't to bad. You have a handful of options, but I personally suggest using Tim Pope's [speeddating](https://github.com/tpope/vim-speeddating) plugin. It will provide a nice `<c-a>` visually mode mapping.

However if you want a quick and dirty mapping here you go:

```
xnoremap <silent> <c-a> :<c-u>exe "'<,'>norm! ".min([col("'<"),col("'>")]).'<bar>'.v:count1."\<c-a>"<cr>
```

Since you mentioned alignment you may also want to look at godlygeek's [Tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) plugin. Drew over at [vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org) did a [screencast on using tabular](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/aligning-text-with-tabular-vim/).

If you decide to make your own mapping/function/plugin I would also suggest you look into the following:

```
:h :s
:h /\%V
:h sub-replace-expression
:h printf(
```